# Encoding/Decoding with power series

Tags: encryption, encoding, decode, power-series

#### Intro

I got a string `original`, which was encoded (using the procedure below), then encrypted with rsa and then decoded again, so I'm left with a ciphertext `s`.

To get back to the `original` plaintext I'd encode `s`, then decrypt and then decode again.

#### Encoding

Each character in `s` gets encoded (using the function `x`) like this:
 `x(A)=0, x(B)=1, ..., x(Z)=25`

Then the message, with `k` amount of characters, gets encoded (using the function `y`) like this:
 `encoded_msg = y(s) = x(s0)*260 + x(s1)*261 + x(s2)*262 + ... x(sk)*26k-1`

#### The problem

Now, if i do this for `original="ABCD"` for example, that would lead to

`y(x(original)) = 0 + 1*26 + 2*676 + 3*17576 = 54106`.

<sub>(encrypt → decrypt → `54106`)</sub>

`decode ?`

My question is: If all I got are the functions `x` and `y` and a result `54106`, how do I decode back to `"ABCD"`?